# Cordova inAppBrowser - executeScript causes blank page for Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

Running the code below successfully loads the page but causes it to go blank when running `executeScript`:

```js
var ref = window.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank');

ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(){
  ref.executeScript({ code: 'window.myValue' }, function(val){
    console.log(val);
  }
});
```

This works fine for iOS, but not for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing a complete update of the Cordova project (plugins, etc).